# Trouble running bundle exec rspec

Tags: ruby, bundle

Hello I am having trouble running the command **"bundle exec rspec"** in vscode. Every time I run the command I get an output of **"No examples found"**. I have two files in a lib folder and two files inside spec folder. I have updated my bundle and have "_spec" in all my spec files. First time debugging no idea what I am doing.

Comment: do those spec files define any actual specs?

Comment: Sorry I am really new to this and I don't know what you mean or how to check

Comment: What do you have in those files?